# search for multiple conditioned string with awk

Tags: linux, unix, sed, awk

I have a set of data that looks like this

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
ABC1    DEF1    GHI1    cond1
ABC2    DEF2    GHI2    cond1-cond2
ABC3    DEF3    GHI3    cond2/cond1
ABC4    DEF4    GHI4    cond2 cond1
ABC5    DEF5    GHI5    cond4/cond1
ABC6    DEF6    GHI6    cond1
ABC7    DEF7    GHI7    mcond1
ABC8    DEF8    GHI8    cond2
ABC9    DEF9    GHI9    cond1 at 50
ABCa    DEFa    GHIa    con cond1
ABCb    DEFb    GHIb    no. cond1
ABCc    DEFc    GHIc    cond1 something
ABCc    DEFc    GHIc    Mcond1
```

I am trying to write a couple of commands to separate the data according to the "col4" to get:

1. A file that contains the string "cond1" with ANYTHING before or after it EXCEPT for the "M" and "m" letters. I am currently using this command (which doesn't exclude M and m, obviously) for this:

   ```
   awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} $4 ~ /.cond1/ || $4 ~ /cond1./ ' /filepath.tab
   ```

   please also not that the 4th, 9th and the 11th rows of data contains spaces between "cond1" and other strings, I want this INCLUDED in the file. (does the "." in the command include spaces?)
2. I wrote a command to get a file that contains "cond1" ONLY in the "col4"

   ```
   awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} $4 ~ /^cond1$/ '  /filepath.tab
   ```

   it is working fine with most of the data, though i am getting these 2 bugs in the results:

   ```
   ABC9    DEF9    GHI9    cond1 at 50
   ABCc    DEFc    GHIc    cond1 something
   ```

Can anyone please help me with these 2 commands?
Thanks.

I am looking for an output of 3 files that does not contain any duplicates, here's an example:
File1 (containing all the combinations with cond1):

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
ABC2    DEF2    GHI2    cond1-cond2
ABC3    DEF3    GHI3    cond2/cond1
ABC4    DEF4    GHI4    cond2 cond1
ABC5    DEF5    GHI5    cond4/cond1
ABC9    DEF9    GHI9    cond1 at 50
ABCa    DEFa    GHIa    con cond1
ABCb    DEFb    GHIb    no. cond1
ABCc    DEFc    GHIc    cond1 something
```

File2 (containing cond1 alone):

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
ABC1    DEF1    GHI1    cond1
ABC6    DEF6    GHI6    cond1
```

File3 (contains anything that wasn't included in file1 and file2):

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
ABC7    DEF7    GHI7    mcond1
ABC8    DEF8    GHI8    cond2
ABCc    DEFc    GHIc    Mcond1
```

Note that the total rows of the 3 files is the same as the original file
I am sorry if this sounds rather complicated, but this is the case I actually have.

Comment: What is your desired output!

Comment: What is the separator between column? is it tab? if its space 11th rows 4th column will not contain `cond1`. It's 5th column there

Comment: Yes it is a tab separated file, and sometimes there is a single space between words. (and i am sure it is not a different columns, because this was a big file and i used cut to take these 4 columns out only)

Comment: See my answer. it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that column 4 has spaces in and your file isn't formatted as expected try `awk -F'\t' {print $4} file` and notice it's probably not what you expect.

First turn the file in CSV format with `sed`

```
$ sed 's/\s\+/,/;s/\s\+/,/;s/\s\+/,/;' file
col1,col2,col3,col4
ABC1,DEF1,GHI1,cond1
ABC2,DEF2,GHI2,cond1-cond2
ABC3,DEF3,GHI3,cond2/cond1
ABC4,DEF4,GHI4,cond2 cond1
ABC5,DEF5,GHI5,cond4/cond1
ABC6,DEF6,GHI6,cond1
ABC7,DEF7,GHI7,mcond1
ABC8,DEF8,GHI8,cond2
ABC9,DEF9,GHI9,cond1 at 50
ABCa,DEFa,GHIa,con cond1
ABCb,DEFb,GHIb,no. cond1
ABCc,DEFc,GHIc,cond1 something
ABCc,DEFc,GHIc,Mcond1
```

This only converts the first 3 whitespace groups to commas leaving col4 as you want. To store the change in the file use the `-i` option:

```
sed -i 's/\s\+/,/;s/\s\+/,/;s/\s\+/,/;' file
```

Now the field separator `,` can be used.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS="\t"} NR==1{print $1,$2,$3,$4} $4~/cond1./|| $4~/[^mM]cond1/{print $1,$2,$3,$4}' file
col1    col2    col3    col4
ABC2    DEF2    GHI2    cond1-cond2
ABC3    DEF3    GHI3    cond2/cond1
ABC4    DEF4    GHI4    cond2 cond1
ABC5    DEF5    GHI5    cond4/cond1
ABC9    DEF9    GHI9    cond1 at 50
ABCa    DEFa    GHIa    con cond1
ABCb    DEFb    GHIb    no. cond1
ABCc    DEFc    GHIc    cond1 something

$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS="\t"} NR==1{print $1,$2,$3,$4} $4~/^cond1$/{print $1,$2,$3,$4}' file 
col1    col2    col3    col4
ABC1    DEF1    GHI1    cond1
ABC6    DEF6    GHI6    cond1

$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";OFS="\t"} $4!~/cond1/ || $4~/[Mm]cond1/{print $1,$2,$3,$4}' file
col1    col2    col3    col4
ABC7    DEF7    GHI7    mcond1
ABC8    DEF8    GHI8    cond2
ABCc    DEFc    GHIc    Mcond1
```

Just redirect to save the newfiles `awk '{...}' > file1`.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your command. for the first command (after turning this into a comma separated file), even the spaces between words turned into commas. so I lost the "cond1 at 50", "cond1 something", "cond2 cond1" , "con cond1" and "no. cond1" fields.

Comment: @Error404 no the `sed` command is constructed in a way to only replace the first 3 whitespace groups with commas, I have updated my answer to explain this.

Comment: yes dude, Thanks for your answer... now that I understand the command, I know how to catch a fish and I will eat everyday :)

Answer (score 1):

As your fields are tab separated use `FS="\t"` in `BEGIN` block. Also your condition is not proper. So I have changed it.

```
awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1; FS="\t"; } $4 ~ /cond1/ && $4 !~ /mcond1|cond1m/' data
```

Comment: Thanks for the command. Actually this is working in a good way, but i want to add something to this command. if i had this in col4 "mcond1 cond1" so if mcond1 and cond1 are there at the same time, i want it to be included, if mcond1 was alone or with anything else, then NO. how do i say this?

Comment: This overmatches, includes line 1 and 6, plus no header.

Answer (score 1):

You could accomplish the task with a single pass. Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk file
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    FS="\t"
}

NR==1 {
    r=$0
    next
}

{
    i = ($4 == "cond1" ? 2 : ($4 ~ /cond1/ && $4 !~ /[Mm]cond1/ ? 1 : 3))
    print (!a[i]++ ? r ORS : "") $0 > "file" i ".txt"
}
```

Results of `grep . file[1-3].txt`:

```
file1.txt:col1  col2    col3    col4
file1.txt:ABC2  DEF2    GHI2    cond1-cond2
file1.txt:ABC3  DEF3    GHI3    cond2/cond1
file1.txt:ABC4  DEF4    GHI4    cond2 cond1
file1.txt:ABC5  DEF5    GHI5    cond4/cond1
file1.txt:ABC9  DEF9    GHI9    cond1 at 50
file1.txt:ABCa  DEFa    GHIa    con cond1
file1.txt:ABCb  DEFb    GHIb    no. cond1
file1.txt:ABCc  DEFc    GHIc    cond1 something
file2.txt:col1  col2    col3    col4
file2.txt:ABC1  DEF1    GHI1    cond1
file2.txt:ABC6  DEF6    GHI6    cond1
file3.txt:col1  col2    col3    col4
file3.txt:ABC7  DEF7    GHI7    mcond1
file3.txt:ABC8  DEF8    GHI8    cond2
file3.txt:ABCc  DEFc    GHIc    Mcond1
```

Alternatively, here's the one-liner:

```
awk -F "\t" 'NR==1 { r=$0; next } { i = ($4 == "cond1" ? 2 : ($4 ~ /cond1/ && $4 !~ /[Mm]cond1/ ? 1 : 3)); print (!a[i]++ ? r ORS : "") $0 > "file" i ".txt" }' file
```